# Distance metric with different sized lists (Python)

Tags: python, list, scipy, probability

I am trying to find the jensen shannon distance metric between two distributions. However I am getting a ValueError because the two lists (probability distributions) are not the same size. How can I overcome this?

Here is the current code:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
distance.jensenshannon([0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.30], [0.30, 0.50, 0.20])
>> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,)(3,)
```

Comment: can you compare between 2 different shapes (5x1) and (3x1) ?

Comment: I think you have a mathematical problem, not a programming one. The Jensen-Shannon divergence measures closeness of two probability distributions defined on the _same_ sample space. What's your sample space here? Your first list would suggest a sample space containing five points, while your second list would make sense for a sample space containing three points.

Comment: That is a good point @MarkDickinson. It seems to be a mathematical issue since sample space needs to be the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the function is unable to compare between 2 different shapes (5x1) and (3x1). I've tried this with both vectors of the same shape (5x1), and it works

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
distance.jensenshannon([0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.30], [0.30, 0.50, 0.20, 0.1, 0.2])
```

output

```
0.30985287648299353
```

And when I compare 2 identical vectors, the distance output is zero

```
distance.jensenshannon([0.30, 0.50, 0.20, 0.1, 0.2], [0.30, 0.50, 0.20, 0.1, 0.2])
```